How can I change an IP obtain from DHCP into a String? -PowerShelll
I am just getting started in powershell. My goal is to run a script that takes a users input (a device name) and searches the DHCP server and returns just the IP. It then converts the IP into a string and displays it on the console. I did some reseach online and have put together the following script.
$DeviceName = Read-Host "Enter the name of the device" 
$PC= $DeviceName + ".companyname.com"

$DHCPServer = 'dhcpserver.com'
$scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $DHCPServer
foreach ($scope in $scopes){
 
  Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer |
   Where-Object hostname -eq $PC |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress |
     select -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
  
}

$NewIP =

The output is
192.168.x.x
I just can't figure out how to take that IP(just the numbers) and make it into a string.
I tried putting the output into a variable. I tried exporting to see what it would look like but my txt is blank. I have been reseaching for 3 hours now at my wits end. Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

I don't have access to a DHCP server at the moment to try but have you tried using the .toString() method on the result? You may inspect the resulting object with a Get-Member. Regardless of that - why / whatfor do need the output as string?

Or do you mean to output only the IP without the header? ... this is easy - just use -ExpandProperty instead of -Property ‍♂️

To expand on @olaf’s comment, select-object -property “my property” returns an object filtered to contain just the specified property / properties, but it’s still an object with properties. select-object -expandproperty ”my property” on the other hand returns the value contained in the specified property for each input object.

So I left out the second part of my project, but basically I need that IP to be in a string so I can put it into a variable and then call that variable when update a DNS record. I got the DNS part to work and it needs to parse an IP in a string format. So I gues my complete question is how do I get an IP converted into a string then stored in a variable called $NewIP.

I don't see any attempts to store an IP in variable $newip like you state you tried.  If  -Expandproperty doesn't give what you desire, you should actually show what you've tried so we can help you.

I have expended on it and now just get the IP but dont know  to put the result of the for loop into a variable.

Try $NewIP = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer | making the result a variable within the loop.

Putting the entire thing in $NewIP does not work.

Even if you also within the loop you put $NewIP to show it's output inside the loop? I don't have a Windows DHCP server to test this but you can also (Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer | Where-Object hostname -eq $PC ).IPAddress or something like that. If the output if just one value, you should be able to [string]$NewIP as last line inside the loop. Give those methods a shot.

I put the foreach loop in the variable $NewDnsIp variable and it works. Thanks!

Now mind you, I am an amature in powershell, so there will be better ways to solve this problem. All this is done to help improve my understanding of Powershell. Bascially this is a clunky version of "ipconfig /flushdns".  Thank you all for your input.
> # The purpose of this script is to mannually update a DNS record. A device name needs to be added.
> 
> 
> #Prompt users to input device name

 $DeviceName = Read-Host "Enter the name of the device" 
> 
> $PC= $DeviceName + ".companyname.com"
> 
> $DHCPServer = 'DHCPServer.com' $scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope
> -ComputerName $DHCPServer $newDnsIp = foreach ($scope in $scopes){    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName
> $DHCPServer |    Where-Object hostname -eq $PC |
>     Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress |
>      select -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
> 
> }
> 
> Out-String -InputObject $newDnsIp
> 
> $oldDnsEntry = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName dc1 -ZoneName
> companyname.com -Name $DeviceName
> 
> $newDnsEntry = $oldDnsEntry.clone()
> 
> $newDnsEntry.RecordData.IPv4Address =
> [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($newDnsIp)
> 
> Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -NewInputObject $newDnsEntry
> -OldInputObject $oldDnsEntry -ZoneName companyname.com -ComputerName dc1

